# Yii2 API routing with versions

Tags: php, api, yii2

I'm having a problem getting my Yii2 application API setup. We have a website up and running and I've been tasked to setup a API for 3rd parties to connect to us to perform certain function calls. I've been reading the docs and did some googling and found [this site](https://github.com/deerawan/yii2-advanced-api) that has a base setup for website and api. I installed it to see how it was setup, so I could try and apply it to my site.

I'm hitting the API section of the directory structure just fine, but I can't for the life of me figure out how the routing is supposed to work.

My directory structure is now as follows:

```
root
--api
----config
------main.php
----modules
------v1
--------controllers
----------SearchController.php
--------models
----------Search.php
----------ApiUser.php
--------Module.php
----runtime
----web
------assets
--assets
--commands
--config
---common
---site1
--controllers
----base
----common
----site1
--mail
--migrations
--models
--modules
--runtime
--vendor
----vendor_dirs
--views
--web
```

My apache config is as follows for the api alias:

```
Alias /api /var/www/website.com/api/web
<Directory "/var/www/webiste.com/api/web">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

I'm confused to as to how I'm supposed to setup the `url_manager` section of the config file so that `www.website.com/api/v1/search/do-search` will hit the `\api\modules\v1\controllers\SearchController::actionDoSearch()` function.

My config looks as follows

```
'id' => 'app-api',
'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
'bootstrap' => ['log'],
'modules' => [
    'v1' => [
        'basePath' => '@app/modules/v1',
        'class' => 'api\modules\v1\Module',
        'controllerNamespace' => 'api\modules\v1\controllers',
    ],
],
'components' => [
    'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'api\v1\models\ApiUser',
        'enableAutoLogin' => false,
        'enableSession' => false,
    ],
    'log' => [
        'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
        'targets' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                'levels' => ['error', 'warning', 'info', 'trace'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'enableStrictParsing' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                'controller' => 'v1/search',
                'pluralize' => false,
                'extraPatterns' => [
                    'GET do-search' => 'do-search'
                ]
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

I've read through the [routing guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-routing.html) on the Yii2 website, but it didn't really shed any light on the subject.

**update**

So after tweaking my config, I think I managed to make some headway, but I'm still not there yet.

I'm now getting the following error:

```
ReflectionException

Class api\modules\v1\Module does not exist
```

My namespace in the module is as follows:

```
namespace api\modules\v1;

class ApiModule extends \yii\base\Module
{
```

So it seems that the namespace is not registering property, or the base path for the module is not correct.

Any help explaining things, so I can better understand would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

**SUCCESS**

I'm an idiot. The Module.php file was not in the `v1` directory, but actually one directory down.

Comment: have a look at [this post by Joachim Werner](https://www.diggin-data.de/dd-cms/blog/post/view/id/1004/name/Creating+a+REST+API+for+Yii2-basic-template). it may be useful to you as it already was to me (when doing [this](https://github.com/tunecino/Yii2_foundation-apps/tree/master/backend)).

Comment: @SalemOuerdani - The URL is generating errors.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add your module to modules section:

   ```
   'modules' => [
           'v1' => [
               'class' => 'app\modules\v1\Module',
               'basePath' => '@app/modules/v1',
               'controllerNamespace' => 'app\modules\v1\controllers'
           ]
   ```
2. Add url rules for REST controller:

   ```
    'urlManager' => [
                   'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
                   'enableStrictParsing' => false,
                   'showScriptName' => false,
                   'rules' => [
                       [
                           'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                              'controller' => [ 'v1/search']
                       ],
                       'GET v1/search/do-search' => 'v1/search/do-search',//actually should work without this line
   ```

When creating new controller add it to controller section in url rules.

Comment: I've tweaked my config, but I'm still having issues.